# Fiddler: Suppress string "Fiddler:" in HTTP error message

Tags: fiddler, http-status-codes

When browsing/calling a non-existent URL while using Fiddler, the browser displays the following error message: "Fiddler: DNS lookup for  failed. No such host is known."

Is there any way to suppress the "Fiddler:" part, i.e. the browser just displaying the plain error message ("DNS lookup ...")?

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler has an OnReturningError event in FiddlerScript (Rules > Customize Rules) that allows you to rewrite all of the returned error messages in any way you want. The event's signature matches all of the other On* events in that script.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
FiddlerApplication.BeforeReturningError += delegate(Session oS)
{
  oS.utilSetResponseBody(oS.GetResponseBodyAsString().Replace("[Fiddler]", String.Empty).Trim());
};
```